# "Rollback" multi-DDL migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, undo

*Big edit, I talk of abstract "actions" now, not the specific ones I had before; those were just an example.*

## Scenario

I have a migration:

```
class XyzMigration < ActiveRecord:Migration
  def change
    first_action :a do ...
    some_action :b do ...
    other_action :c do ...
  end
end
```

If all 3 actions (whatever they are; creating tables, indexes, modifying columns etc.) succeed, then all is fine.

But: If action `b` fails, then the migration will successfully execute `a` and then stop.

## Problem

Herein lies the problem: now `a` has been done, whatever it was, but the migration is not complete. That is, when I retry the migration (after manually fixing the problem that lead to the failure of `b`), I get a failure that `a` has already been done, and I have to manually undo `a`.

## What I would expect

I wish to tell Rails that it is safe to undo all completed steps if a latter step of the migration fails. Technically, Rails is able to do that because a) the undo mechanism exists (we can use `rake db:rollback` do undo a complete migration and b) Rails knows for each step whether it is reversible. So assuming all previous steps before the failed one are reversible, it knows that it is safe to undo.

Is there an option, flag, mechanism to do that? I do not wish to program the logic myself, neither by checking beforehand whether the action needs to be done nor by catching exceptions.

Comment: Do you use MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Check for if a table exists before creating a table:

```
# In Rails 2, 3 & 4:
unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?('a')
  create_table :a do ...
end
unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?('b')
  create_table :b do ...
end
# ...



# In rails 5:
unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.data_source_exists?('a')
  create_table :a do ...
end
unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.data_source_exists?('b')
  create_table :b do ...
end
# ...
```

Comment: See the clarification I added to the question.